# Error: "local variable 'myData' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqtgraph

Good evening,

I am new to python. I was working through a tutorial while trying to develop my live graph plotting data from a LIDAR sensor. I was getting the error " UnboundLocalError: local variable 'myData' referenced before assignment" Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys  # We need sys so that we can pass argv to QApplication
import os
import serial
import csv
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic, QtCore
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot

arduinoSerialData = serial.Serial('com3', 9600)
NameofCSV = 'data2.csv'
style.use('ggplot')

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphWidget)

        if (arduinoSerialData.inWaiting()>0):
            myData = arduinoSerialData.readline()
            xn = datetime.now()
            Time = xn.strftime('%H%M%S')

        with open(NameofCSV, 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ')

            info = (float(myData), float(Time))
            writer.writerow(info)

            # print(float(myData), Time)
            x1,y1 = np.loadtxt(NameofCSV, unpack = True, delimiter = ' ')

        self.x = x1
        self.y = y1  

        self.graphWidget.setBackground('w')

        pen = pg.mkPen(color=(255, 0, 0))
        self.data_line =  self.graphWidget.plot(self.y, self.x, pen=pen)
                # ... init continued ...
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(50)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_plot_data)
        self.timer.start()

    def update_plot_data(self):

        self.x = self.x[1:]  # Remove the first y element.
        self.x.append(self.x[-1] + 1)  # Add a new value 1 higher than the last.

        self.y = self.y[1:]  # Remove the first 
        self.y.append(self.y)  # Add a new random value.

        self.data_line.setData(self.x, self.y)  # Update the data.

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

So, `myData` only gets initialized in this block:

```
if (arduinoSerialData.inWaiting()>0):
            myData = arduinoSerialData.readline()
```

if that `if` clause doesn't evaluate to True, it'll skip it, and later on you'll be using `myData` without it being initialized: `info = (float(myData), float(Time))`

You can initialize myData to some starting value up at the top, or ensure the code that sets it to a value is always run before its value is used.

Happy Coding!